# Android Studio - Create Mock Progress Bar

Tags: java, android, android-studio, progress-bar

I'm creating a mock application in Android Studio and on the loading screen I would like to create a 'mock' progress bar that take 10 seconds to fill. This is just to show what the app will look like once it is fully coded.

I'm not experienced with android studio very at all so please bare with my inexperience, but at the moment I have created a for loop to run 10 times incrementing the progress bar by 10% each time with the following code:

```
private ProgressBar progress;

public void mockprogressbar (ProgressBar progress){

     progress = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar);
     progress.setMax(100);

     for(int i = 1; i < 11; ++i){
        try {
            Thread.sleep(1000);
            progress.setProgress(i*10);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
     }  
}
```

I hoped that when this method was run when an image was selected that I would have a 'mock' progress bar that would wait a second then increment itself by 10% until it reach 100%, however what I have instead is when I run my AVD the code runs till complete and skips to display the progress bar completely full.

I was wondering if I needed to somehow 'update' the progress bar after each incrementation or whether this is even possible in Android Studio. If there is another simpler way I would also be interested to know, thanks for any help in advance and sorry for my inexperience again :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no difference in how the ProgressBar works with android studio and eclipse.
Try this sample code and it works:

```
 private ProgressDialog progress;
   @Override
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
      progress = new ProgressDialog(this);
   }


   public void open(View view){
      progress.setMessage("Downloading Music :) ");
      progress.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_HORIZONTAL);
      progress.setIndeterminate(true);
      progress.show();

   final int totalProgressTime = 100;

   final Thread t = new Thread(){

   @Override
   public void run(){

      int jumpTime = 0;
      while(jumpTime < totalProgressTime){
         try {
            sleep(200);
            jumpTime += 5;
            progress.setProgress(jumpTime);
         } catch (InterruptedException e) {
           // TODO Auto-generated catch block
           e.printStackTrace();
         }

      }

   }
   };
   t.start();
   }
```

Comment: thanks that works fine, think it was a problem with my project